# Firebug inactive classes - Firefox issue JW Player

Tags: javascript, dom, slider, firebug, jwplayer

The problem occurs in in a JS Slider where I want to play a .mp4 video through the embeded JW-player The weird thing is, it just occurs in Firefox. After pressing the button the object (screenshot one)

[image]

should be added to the DOM - but the class is visualized grey and looks kind of inactive...

[image]

Interesting is when I execute fancybox before (just open and close a picture) and then pressing the play button the class is active in firebug and the video starts

[image]

As I said it's working in IE, Chrome, Safari.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?

Comment: I can give you access to the platform in a defined time window - where can I post or contact you? the result will be posted here...

Comment: http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us

Comment: No problem, will take a look.